# Can I use gcc built-in functions in MSVC?

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, atomic, built-in

I want to use GCC atomic memory access built-in functions in MSVC(v143) environment.

How can i use them with MSVC??

I know that i can use them by changing compiler to clang, but it is hard to change the compiler in my case.

Comment: "Built-in" functions means that the functions are built into the specific compiler. They are non-standard and non-portable. So no, you can't use GCC-specific functions in other compilers. But it's likely that MSVC have *similar* built-in functions, perhaps that does the same thing but with different names. So if you want help you need to tell us what functions specifically you're using.

Comment: Have you tried clang-cl?  It aims for compatibility with MSVC, but still supports GNU C extensions.  (It's not 100% compatible with MSVC inline asm; MSVC supports leaving a value in EAX and falling off the end of a non-`void` function to return a value.  In clang-cl, that's undefined behaviour.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You either compile with MSVC or GCC. If you don't use GCC, you don't have GCC's functions. Why it would be hard to change a compiler in your case?

Comment: Clang (including `clang-cl` which aims to be a drop-in replacement for MSVC) supports most of the same GNU C builtin functions, including the `__atomic` builtins (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html).  They're not limited to GCC specifically.